# MySQL php array - find values from array that do not match query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am currently working on a live site and need to double check my code before I implement it. I cannot do this on jsfiddle :(

I have two variables:

```
$user_id (users user id - one only)
$job_id (an array of job ids that could number from 0 to numerous)
```

What I need to do is check the database that there are entires that match both the `job_id` and the `user_id`. If there is no match then I need to return each `job_id` that does not match:

```
$job_id=join(',',$job_id);
$query="SELECT job_id FROM table WHERE job_id NOT IN('$job_id') AND user_id='$user_id'";
....do myslqi query etc
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $no_match[]=$row['job_id'];
}
```

I am not 100% sure if this is going to return the job_ids that do not have the relevant user_ids. My colleague suggested looping through each job_id and performing a seperate query for each one but this sounds really bad practice to me.

I am also intrested in finding any resources for quickly testing mysql queries away from the live site - links would be grateful :)

Comment: If you're using `mysqli`, you **must** use the [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) method to compose your queries correctly. You should not be using string concatenation or interpolation to do this.

Comment: If you want to test your queries, you can use [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: @tadman thanks for this advice - looks pretty important.

Comment: @tadman It's hard to use `bind_param` with a variable number of parameters.

Comment: It can be tricky, but it's not hard, and it's something you must do. What's harder is recovering from a SQL injection bug that's been exploited. In your example you only have two values, it's trivial to do it correctly. You just need to add `?` to your query string and a value to a values array at the same time so things match up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does it in one query:

```
SELECT job_id
FROM table
WHERE user_id = '$user_id'
AND NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT *
   FROM table
   WHERE user_id = '$user_id'
   AND job_id IN ($job_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

This query returns rows that doesn't have the job id you specified but has the user_id,

```
 $query="SELECT job_id FROM table WHERE job_id NOT IN('$job_id') AND user_id='$user_id'";
```

if you want the job ids that doesn't have the user id then use.

```
 $query="SELECT job_id FROM table WHERE job_id IN('$job_id') AND user_id!='$user_id'";
```

Comment: Thanks - I think my statement needs a bit of thinking about but I think you are correct.